# render inputs on page load with selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio buttons that render/hide certain fields when selected. However, its not showing  up onLoad. How do I make the DOM take account this into account?

**[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertmaxrees/nvfs5c0r/9/)**

```
var hideOrShowInputs = function() {
  var $this = $(this),
   $groupToShow = $($this.data('inputgroup'));

  $('.inputgroup').hide();
  $groupToShow.show();
};
```

I suspect this part is where the culprit is, but im not sure what im doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is `document` within anonymous function handler at `.ready(handler)` .

Try using `Function.prototype.bind()` to set `this` to `$(".slim-column input:first")` within `.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(hideOrShowInputs.bind($(".slim-column input:first")));
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nvfs5c0r/14/